# Log database updates with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

How to log all database updates, inserts or deletes in CakePHP made using pure SQL?

example:

$this->Car->query('update cars set color = "red" ');

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Extend whatever datasource you're using and override the `_execute()`
method to log and pass back to the parent.

For example, let's assume you're currently using dbo_mysql. That means
your db config is something like this:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            // ...
    )
}
```

so change 'driver' to 'mysql_with_log', and create the file app/model/
datasources/dbo/mysql_with_log.php :

```
<?php
require (LIBS . 'model' . DS . 'datasources' . DS . 'dbo' . DS .'dbo_mysql.php');
class DboMysqlWithLog extends DboMysql {
   function _execute($sql) {
         $this->log($sql);
         return parent::_execute($sql);
   }
}
?>
```

Here is the [Reference link](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Log-SQL-queries-td1281970.html).

You can also use [Cake debug kit](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debug-kit).

This plugin will also help you to save SQL Logs. Here is the link to [download Debug Kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit).

Comment: If i need to log also content that was in database before update/delete?

Comment: For that, you will have to always make an insert query with the new data, and set the `status='disabled'` for the previous entry for the given record.